# Integrating Service Now with Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, servicenow

i am trying to have an integration between service now and azure devops .
If any one can answer below question it be much appreciated.
How to trigger Azure DevOps pipeline automatically on Approving the Change Request in ServiceNow ?
I am approaching with rest API method to call AzureDevops from servicenow plateform.

Does anyone has done something similar and can help me here by listing steps to do so?

Comment: Even I am pretty much interested in this solution, but till now no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Service Connection to you ServiceNow instance and then add a Gate in your Release pipeline which creates the Change Request in ServiceNow and then waits for it's status to change.

This provides a good guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/servicenow?view=azure-devops and your gate will end up looking something like this:

[image]

You can also use an existing CR but then you'll need a way to supply that to the pipeline on creation of the release.

Comment: Hey thanks for the link, I tried this  before and it only allows the change management stuff, But is there any way i can create a Rest API to trigger the Azure Devops pipeline from Service Now instance ?

Comment: What's your desired workflow, create a CR in ServiceNow and have that trigger the release, bear in mind if you have a multi stage release you'd have had to get it at least as far as QA first so it's a bit disjointed to trigger the last part from ServiceNow imho?

Answer (score -2):

In the azure devops, we can Install and configure ServiceNow DevOps extension for Azure DevOps to send build and release notifications from your Azure pipeline to ServiceNow DevOps application.
For more details, you can refer this doc: [Azure DevOps integration with DevOps](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/quebec-devops/page/product/enterprise-dev-ops/concept/azure-devops-integration-dev-ops.html)

Comment: This extension only works one way, I mean if you want to trigger Azure DevOps from ServiceNow, it doesn't help.